# Best hook for a function which adds shortcodes to the system?

Tags: loop, hooks, init

I have a plugin released, and one of my customers was reporting a problem where the plugin was outputting ads in the header area of their website.

I have a function defined which contains my shortcode definitions, for example, the function contains a few of these `add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'my_function' );`

I am executing the function via the following command `add_action( 'init', 'add_my_shortcodes');`

Doing it thisway causes a conflich with my plugin (which outputs adsense ads) and the google analytics in the header).

I was testing different hook positions for my add_action, and it appears that `add_action( 'loop_start', 'add_my_shortcodes');`

If my plugin is for outputting of ads, what is the best place to hook? I need it to be available anywhere in the template, or content. For example, they can put it in posts, sidebar widgets, or straight hard coded into the theme via a `do_shortcode` in their template files.

In order to ensure my shortcode is registered before any content is generated, but AFTER their header scripts, I moved my way down this list http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference until the ads worked properly. I ended up landing on the hook `loop_start` which doesn't sound like an ideal place to hook into.

Can anyone suggest the best hook location so that it is executed before any output, but after the opening `<body>` tag? I'm assuming I need to get as close to the `<body>` tag as possible, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the `init` hook, rather than with your shortcode callback itself? Please **edit your question** to include your shortcode callback.

Comment: When you say shortcode callback, do you mean the function in which the shortcode executes? It's very long and complicated. Actually broke across a couple functions. I am not certain that it's not part of my function. The fact that moving the hook location around seemingly fixes the issue leads me to think that their theme (genesis framework) has a conflicting hook. That's why I'm trying a different hook. The standard `init` hook works on dozens and dozens of other installations.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have a shortcode defined, but you want it to execute *outside of the post content*? And you're trying to use a particular action hook to accomplish that?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Sorry, I don't know all the correct terms. My shortcode outputs adsense ads. If a customer wants to hard code it in their theme files with a `do_shortcode` command, they should be able to. The topmost location on the page where they should be allowed to insert ads is just after the opening body tag. Therefor I don't want my shortcodes to work  if they are called in the `<head>` of the page. That's why I don't want to use the `init` hook, and I'd rather use a hook like `body_open` if such a hook existed.

Comment: You may be right about my code conflicting. I know it has to do with their theme, but I'm going to see what I may be able to change in my shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following things correctly, I think the problem is that your shortcode callback *echoes*, rather than *returns* its content - and that you have it set up that way in order for the shortcode content to output *outside of the post content*.

If that's the case, you're taking the wrong approach.

Your shortcode callback *must* **return**, rather than **echo**, its output. By *echoing* its content, you're experiencing the issues you've observed:

> I have a plugin released, and one of my customers was reporting a
>   problem where the plugin was outputting ads in the header area of
>   their website...
>
> Doing it thisway causes a conflich with my plugin (which outputs
>   adsense ads) and the google analytics in the header).

To use the shortcode outside of the post content, it must be executed via [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[myshortcode]' ); ?>
```

How that `do_shortcode()` call gets added to the template in the correct location is entirely Theme-dependent. If the Theme provides an appropriate hook, then you can hook into it. If not, you may have to modify a template file via Child Theme.

Comment: Ah, fellow bearded helper! My shortcode does in fact return the content. I even tried ob_clean and return ob_get_clean() just to see if anything was being echo'd by mistake, and it wasn't. Also if it was echoing it, then many many more customers would be reporting the issue.

Comment: Hmm... then I'm really struggling to follow your problem. Can you try to provide a bit more context: how exactly the shortcode is being used in the template, and what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Sorry Chip. Here is the problem http://awesomescreenshot.com/0341zpli55 you can see that there are two ads above everything, and it is inserted within their analytics code. This is how the site looks if I use the `init` hook. If I change the hook to `loop_start` this is what happens http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e11zply95 Nothing has changed other than the hook.

Comment: And again we go back to the callback. Without seeing the actual code, it is nearly impossible to determine where the problem is.

Comment: Ok, well I'll work on my code. I'll report back if I get it fixed.

Comment: Unless there is a private way for me to share my code with you, then I'll do that. I just don't want to make it public.

Comment: @Branndon You really think this will work out without showing your code? Or do you think that your snippet is that special that it can't be shared in public? If you do think so, then the question will get closed as this site doesn't support closed source code.

Comment: Kaiser. Yes, I thought this would work when I posted without showing my code. I thought it was related to where I hooked in, and not my code. My code is not special, in fact, it's the opposite reason that I didn't post it. It's more that I'm embarrassed by much of it, it's super long and complex. I know I could do many things better in it, and I didn't come here this time for help with my coding. I came for help with the hooks. It seems though that the hooks aren't the issue, and it's an issue with my coding. Now I will attempt to fix the coding issue myself. If I can't, I'll start a new topic